# Close pop up windows that rises during powershell script execution

Tags: powershell

I'm new with powershell and I'm trying to execute a third party program from command line. In one of the executions path, suddenly a pop up window emerges and the script is paused until I click on the accept button or close that window.

What I need is to avoid that click.

Is it possible to tell the script to close any emerging window or to send an event to close it?
Those windows that suddenly pop up make it impossible for me to achieve my task... Is there any other way to handle this?

[image: This is all the information that help command displays]

Comment: What is the programm you want to run? Maybe you missed a switch.

Comment: It is SysClean.com, I want to analize some folders with it. When it detects some malicious file this pop up is displayed.

Comment: This is very much down to the appliactions implementation. Investigate the available switches you can pass to the executable (most often found when invoking the application with a `-?` or `/?` switch)

Comment: I'll try to fix the execution of the third party program but it is not easy to find usefull documentation about it. Skipping it would be good enough for me and perhaps the most simple.

Comment: To me it looks like that `/FULLSILENT` switch is what you need.  This should let it run without needing any interaction.  So, try this:

`.\SysClean.com /NOGUI /FULLSILENT`

Comment: It doesn't work.
/NOGUI -> Activates console mode
/FULLSILENT -> Disables the messages shown on console during execution

If any malware is found the Damage Clean Engine emerges with a window saying "Clean Failed: TSC_GENCLEAN" even if NC (to disable automatic clean) is activated.
Closing that window allows to keep going with the execution. Is it possible to close the window automatically?

Comment: Excuse me by not answer sooner, I fixed this issue. Through
`Get-Process -PID xxxx | Get-Member`
 I was able to look for related methods and properties and I found this:

`#MainWindowTitle in order to identify the window that I wanted to close
$proc = Get-Process ns | ? {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq "window_name"}` 

`#CloseMainWindow in spite of close in order to close the problematic window
$proc.CloseMainWindow()`